# Select a random FIELD of a row and update it accordingly

Tags: php

I need to build a function that selects a random row of a field, but not any row.

Lets say the fields are called

```
id, user, one, two, three, four,five,six
1,'jack',0,0,0,1,0,0
```

When the function is called I need to update one of the following fields: `one, two, three, four,five,six` that has a value of '0' and set it to '1'. Therefore one field cannot be selected more than once. In reality there are over 10 fields that need this kind of handling. The order has to be random.

I'm still trying to figure out the logic without writing too many lines. Any suggestions?

Comment: real code an real structure are more helpfully than pseudo

Comment: "Random" means one column *could* be selected three or four times in a row. (Roll dice to see why.) Maybe you want to [shuffle the columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)?

Comment: @Catcall Once a field is selected it will be set to 1, so it couldn't be selected twice. But I wasn't even avare of shuffle()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
    function Z($id){
    $array =array('one','two','three'); //field names
     shuffle($array);//radnoise the array

     $update='';
     foreach($array as $k => $a){
        if($k==0){
            $update .="'$a'=1,";//first random field is 1

        }else{
            $update .="'$a'=0,";//all other fields are 0
        }
    }

    $update=rtrim($update,",");//remove last comma

    $q="update table set $update where id=$id";
return $q; //for testing, otherwise run query
}

echo Z('4'); //test it
```

//version 2

```
function ZZ($id){
    $array =array('one','two','three'); //field names
     $value=$array[array_rand($array)];
    $q="update table set '$value'=1 where id=$id";
return $q; //for testing, otherwise run query
}

echo ZZ('4'); //test it
```

Comment: Interesting. I like it, however all other fields are not 0 or set to 0. Eventually the row will have all fields as 1.

Comment: ok, then just update the 1 randomly selected field name. in which case array_rand() should be used.

Comment: What if the returned field is already 1? I could do array_rand again, but what if that one is also 1? What if they all are 1?

Comment: sounds like you have to do a select first to get the non "1" fields. cant see any way to do it with one query

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of a way to select a random column in any database, but if the values are all either 1 or 0, why not just put them all into one? That way you would have a string like `101000100001001` where each digit represents a different "column". You could just use PHP to manipulate it and update your database.

Comment: I never thought of that. I guess it's more convenient to have a separate field for each one.